# User driven session expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I need to give my ASP.NET website users a way to control their session timeout.
I am using `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and `cookies`.

I want to give the users a way to specify how long the session will stay active. The range can vary between a few minutes to 1 day or even more.

I'm using `idleTimeout` (I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149341/difference-between-idletimeout-and-shutdowntimeout/6149360#6149360)).

Also, I save the value entered by the user in the database and using that value I initialize the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`.

I have 2 more concerns: Application Pool and cookie. My website runs under a dedicated App Pool. Do I need to change the `idleTimeout` property for App Pool, too? Not programmatically, of course.

Anyway, to phrase my question: what other settings need to be done in order to have the session expiration dynamically set **and working** no matter what time interval?

Thanks.

EDIT: I am using IIS7 on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is never a good idea have a session time out too long as you will keep busy some resource on the server and if your web app is accessed by lots of different user it could affect the server performance.

Anyway you can just change the session time out programmatically using the below code

```
Session.TimeOut= [=nMinutes]
```

bear in mind that session timeout should be less than Application pool idle timeout, so if you increase session timeout, you have to increase application idle timeout too. Otherwise, application will get recycled. If application is recycled, sessions will expire automatically.

The minimum allowed value is 1 minute and the maximum is 1440 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the session life can be controlled from mamy locations... By the way, I understand the risks of high memory usage, but we don't mind that yet.

Comment: yes it is as after each request the timeout is recalculated (by adding the timeout value to the actual time :-)

Comment: I know that, but I want to find ways to keep the session alive as much as possible, if the user wants that.

Comment: there are some ways you can keep the session alive using JavaScript but again keep an eyes on the performance issue. I know at the moment you don't care about memory issue/server resources but you should always try make you software as much scalable as possible( you never know the future)

Comment: No worries at the moment as the customer want this functionality, so I need to provide. We will solve any related issues (like memory usage) when the time comes. By the way, JS seems unreliable.